# Retrieving data filtered by nested query object in REST

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I need to retrieve products by:

- query(search term)
- area

  - radius
  - coordinates

    - latitude
    - longitude

Sending only radius without coordinates is illegal, and vice versa.
Sending only latitude without longitude is illegal, and vice versa.

How should be URL and query parameters in REST for that?

Comment: Why don't use RAML to documentate the endpoint and then use url templates?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU can you give an example please?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: In restful apps the url is kinda irrelevant, the client must not hard-code any url into its requests but it/you can use `{templates}`  for filtering; you however must documentate them in a raml file.

Comment: An example of how will be in RAML what I described.

Answer (score 0):

You could use query parameters for the search by query string and URI parameters for the search by area.

In any case, you should documentate your API. An example of documentation using RAML is this:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: test
version: v1
/products:
  /by-search-and-by-area/{radius}/{latitude}/{longitude}::
    get:
      queryParameters: 
        q:
          type: string
          minLength: 2
          example: laptop dell
          required: true
    uriParameters: 
      latitude: 
        type: number
        example: 25.45
        required: true
      longitude: 
        type: number
        example: 25.45
        required: true
      radius: 
        type: number
        example: 100
        description: radius in km
        required: true
    get:
      description: returns products by radius and latitude and longitude
```

Comment: I need to search by query and by coordinates simultaneously.

Comment: I should be able to search only by query, and only by coordinates